# Mocking a service in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to follow a tutorial on Jest. I am trying to make a test that includes a mock of my REST service. According to the tutorial I need to add a folder with the name mocks (with two underscore before and after - SO removes those in this editor) in the same level as the src folder. In that folder I create a const with same name as my REST service:

```
const CrawlService = jest.fn(() => 42);
```

Now in my test I have following:

```
import { CrawlService } from "../../../services/CrawlService";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";

describe("CardsButtonContainer", () => {
  it("dsfsdf", async () => {
    var jobsResult = await CrawlService.getJobs(0, 1, 1, 10, 0);
  });
});
```

My expectation would be that Jest would replace my REST service with the mock service, have I misunderstood something here? I get following error:

> Request failed with status code 404

It seems like it is my REST service that is called and not the mocked one.

I guess I somehow must add the function getJobs but I am not sure how to do that when it is from a class? Any pointers are welcome.

I am trying to follow this sample:
[image]

Comment: I suggest you use a library like `fetch-mock` or `nock` to mock the actual endpoint. This allows your front-end code to make actual requests, but the responses will be mocked in your test.

Comment: I am trying to follow a sample, I added an image in my post. He does not use any additional frameworks.

Comment: It looks like that example is mocking the entire `isomorphic-fetch` module. Using a library like `fetch-mock` or `nock` is much simpler and allows you to customize the response from any request.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try. Can you add an answer. I will accept it when I have implemented a working sample. If you should recommend one of the two packages which would you go for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you show in the screen shot mocks the entire `isomorphic-fetch` module. I suggest you instead use a library such as `fetch-mock` or `nock`. Both of these provide an API that allows you to customize responses for testing purposes.